# How to change background color of a CollectionView item based on a ViewModel property?

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a .Net MAUI app that uses CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. I have a CollectionView of buttons bound to a list of DateTime. On pressing any button a command is called that sets SelectedTime property of the ViewModel to a corresponding value.

Here is some ViewModel code:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the time of your appointment.")]
    private DateTime? _selectedTime;

    public List<DateTime> Times { get; set; } = new ()
        { new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 30, 0),
          new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 11, 30, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0),
          new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 13, 30, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 14, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 14, 30, 0),
          new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 15, 30, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 16, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 16, 30, 0) };

    [RelayCommand]
    private void SelectTime(object parameter)
    {
        SelectedTime = (DateTime)parameter;
    }
```

Here is my Page code:

```
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Times}" ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3" Margin="5">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentView Padding="5">
                                <Button Text="{Binding ., StringFormat='{0:hh:mm tt}'}"
                                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectTimeCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                </Button>
                            </ContentView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

The collection of buttons is displayes on the screen, but I cannot figure out how I can make a pressed button change its color, and restore it back when another button is pressed? I guess the color should be bound to the SelectedTime property, but cannot make it work.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if each row was bound to a model that had a Selected property instead of to a DateTime

Comment: So create a `class MyClassNameHere` that has two properties: `DateTime MyDateTimeNameHere`, and `bool Selected`. Set ItemsSource to list of those. When an item is selected, set it’s Selected property (and clear the previous item’s Selected property).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve So then I would not need MyClassNameHere to have bgColor, like in Jessie's answer? Would it be better solution?

Comment: Two alternatives. Either is fine. With bool Selected, you also need to write an IValueConverter that returns color based on that bool. Good technique to learn, but bgColor property is easier for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want each button to change color but is it not the complete row you want to change? I can't ask questions due to low rep. So my answer is to ditch the buttons and go with the SelectionChangedCommand, and the whole row will lit up when you click on it.

```
    <CollectionView
        x:Name="CollectionAppointment"
        Margin="5"
        ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Times, Mode=OneTime}"
        SelectedItem="SelectedItem"
        SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectTimeCommand}"
        SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={RelativeSource Self}}"
        SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:Appointment">
                <ContentView Padding="5">
                    <Label
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat='{0:hh:mm tt}'}"
                        TextColor="Black" />
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

The ViewModel for clearification:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MauiTest.ViewModels
{
    public partial class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Appointment _selectedItem;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<Appointment> _times;
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            Times = new()
            {
                new Appointment{ Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0)}, new Appointment{ Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0)},
                new Appointment{ Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0)},
                new Appointment{ Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 30, 0)}
            };
        }


        [RelayCommand]
        private void SelectTime(Appointment parameter)
        {


        }
    }

    public class Appointment
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the buttons to behave like radio buttons. So when a button is pressed, it should change its color, so the user can see what was selected.

Comment: Isn't that what I mean? If you look at the picture in my answer. How do you want it to be shown? Each row can be styled to your liking.

Comment: Oh, in the code I provided I showed that there are 3 buttons in each row, so that is why I spoke of changing background color of a pressed button rather than of a row. Is it possible with the solution you suggested?

Comment: Ok, that was not clear in your description. I have updated the answer. Now you can style it however you want and it is 3 on each row.

Comment: If I understand correctly, binding should be like this: SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ., SelectTimeCommand}", right? I mean, with the "." Also, it is not clear to me what viewmodels:Appointment is.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer with the ViewModel and the Apointment class. It is a better and more clear way to display data then just using basic DateTime.

Comment: Why is it better?

Comment: It clearly says Appointment as DataType and the Binding to each Label is Time. To me it is better and clearer. But of course that is my humble opinion :-) Clearer means easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do I understand correctly that your code does not intend to change the background of the selected item (which is fine, as SelectedItem has an orange border around it)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. My point being is to use the built in color selection in CollectionView and not trying to do it harder than it is. If you want to change the color of the selected item you look into VisualStateManager where you can set any color for Selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model for your each bound item and add a property (e.g.`BgColor`) to set the background of the button, and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the model. Once you click the button, try to change the value of the property `BgColor`, then the UI will refresh itself.

Based on your code, I created a demo and achieved this function.

You can refer to the following code:

1.create a class `Item` and add the properties we need(`Time`  and `BgColor`).

```
public  class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {  
       // add a property Time
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

       // add background color property
        private Color _bgColor;
        public Color BgColor
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _bgColor, value); }
            get { return _bgColor; }
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

2.create a viewmodel and initialize data

```
public partial class MyViewModel 
{

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public ICommand SelectTimeCommand => new Command(selectedTime);

    private void selectedTime(object obj)
    {
       if (obj != null )
        {
            Item item = obj is Item ? (Item)obj : null;
            item.BgColor = Colors.Purple;

            foreach (Item model in Items)
            {
                //here we can change the value of the passed Item
                if (model != item)
                {
                    model.BgColor = Colors.Blue;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel() {

        Items = new List<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item {  Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0),BgColor= Colors.Blue });
        Items.Add(new Item {  Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0), BgColor = Colors.Blue });
        Items.Add(new Item {  Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0), BgColor = Colors.Blue });
        Items.Add(new Item {  Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0), BgColor = Colors.Blue });
        Items.Add(new Item {  Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0), BgColor = Colors.Blue });
        Items.Add(new Item {  Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 14, 0, 0), BgColor = Colors.Blue });
        Items.Add(new Item {  Time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0), BgColor = Colors.Blue });
    }

}
```

3.bind the `BgColor` on the `yourpage.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiCollectionViewApp.TestPage"
             Title="TestPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiCollectionViewApp.ViewModels"
             >

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MyViewModel></viewmodels:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>    
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3" Margin="5"
                        
                        >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView Padding="5">
                      
                        <Button Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat='{0:hh:mm tt}'}"  BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}"
                                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectTimeCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                        </Button>

     
                    </ContentView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Zhang-MSFT Thank you for your answer. Do I really need to derive Item from INotifyPropertyChanged, if I use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm, and _selectedTime has [ObservableProperty] attribute?

Comment: Derive Item from ObservableObject. That already includes INotifyPropertyChanged in itself.